# ReactJS array from usestate is still empty after setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, async-await

please I'm solving one problem (just learning purposes). I'm using `useState()` hook and then, after some timeout I want add next items into array from remote fetch.

My code snippet look like:

```js
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=5';

// asnynchronous call. Yes, it's possible to use axios as well
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    let tasksArray = [];
    await fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        data.results.map((task, index) => {
          // first letter uppercase
          const taskName = task.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + task.name.slice(1);
          tasksArray.push({ id: index, name: taskName });
        });
      });

    console.log('Added tasks:' + tasks.length);
    setTasks(_.isEmpty(tasks) ? tasksArray : [...tasks, tasksArray]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  // Add additional example tasks from api after 5 seconds with
  // fetch fetchData promise
  setTimeout(fetchData, 5000);
}, []);
```

Code works fine with `useEffect()` hook. But in `async` function my array is empty when I add some tasks within five seconds and it will be replaced by fetched data and one empty

I added **Butter** and **Milk** within 5 seconds to my Shopping list

[image]

But after timeout my `tasks` array will be replaced by remote fetched data.

[image]

And as you can see, `tasks` array lenght is 0 (like `console.log()` says)

Please, can you exmplain me, why my tasks array is empty if there exists 2 items before 5 seconds.

Of course, I'm adding my tasks to the list normally after hit `Enter` and `handleSubmit`

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  //creating new task
  setTasks([
    {
      id: [...tasks].length === 0 ? 0 : Math.max(...tasks.map((task) => task.id)) + 1,
      name: newTask,
       isFinished: false,
     },
     ...tasks,
  ]);
  setNewTask('');
}
```

Thanks for help or explain. It the problem that `useEffect` is called after rendering? Of this causing `async` behavior?

Comment: Not sure if it is the problem, but you forgot a spread operator (...) when mering the `tasks` with the `tasksArray` after fetching the data. This causes your state to be `[{}, [{}]]` instead of just a flat array.

Comment: do not use await and then together . choose one of them

Comment: @n9iels right. But I've trying with spread operator before and the result is the same. I edited the line `setTasks(_.isEmpty(tasks) ? tasksArray : [...tasks, tasksArray]);`  to `setTasks(_.isEmpty(...tasks) ? tasksArray : [...tasks, tasksArray]);` but the same result. As you can see, tasks.lenght is 0. But thanks for tip

Comment: @abolfazl shamsollahi Thanks. Do you know why? But OK. I spread it between awayt fetch and then `const response` ... etc... But it didn't solve my problem yet. Array lenght is still 0.

Comment: Btw, whole code is here: https://github.com/zrebec/react-task-manager/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: No, I mean it should be: `setTasks(_.isEmpty(tasks) ? tasksArray : [...tasks, ...tasksArray]);`. Log your state to the console beforfe and after the `setTasks` and you will see the difference.

Comment: Thanks n9iels but same problem with `setTasks(_.isEmpty(...tasks) ? tasksArray : [...tasks, ...tasksArray]);`. But interesting it, that after change the code and save it I have 5 pokemons on the screen and after next 5 seconds next 5. That means, in that case, `tasks` is not empty. But it's empty after refresh the page and add tasks under 5 seconds. Then list only 5 pokekons

Comment: `setTasks((prev) => prev.concat(tasksArray));`

Comment: @R.M. Reza WOW.... It works... Thanks a lot. Length is still 0, I don't know why but it's working. Look

https://imgur.com/a/osopHB9

Please, can you response as a normal message for rating? Or explain to help to others. I can do that after 2 days. I will do it but but I don't understand explain it, why is lenght is 0. Thanks

Comment: @BambiBunny So that I can explain it in detail, please copy all the problematic code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gbsfy6?file=src%2FApp.js After that give me a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand your code fully correctly but my guess is
the fetchData function you have declared might refer to the tasks at the time of declaration.
so every time you call fetchData you might not see the changed tasks state...
if this is the case try using useCallback with the dependency tasks...
what useCallback does is it stores the function in memory and if smth in dependency changes the function's logic changes to dependencies you declared.
If you have used eslint, calling a function inside useEffect will give you error similar to below

```
The ‘fetchOrg’ function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 6) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the ‘fetchOrg’ definition into its own useCallback() Hook
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing. You can place everything inside an useEffect, and I believe the thing you are trying to achieve is a long poll query. (for that you use setInterval() and **you have to clear the function in useEffect**

my solution for you:

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=5';
const request = {method: GET, Headers: {"Content-type":"application/json"}}

useEffect(() => {

   function fetchData(){
      fetch(url, request).then(res => res.json().then(data => {
      data.results.map((task, index) => {
      const taskName = task.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + task.name.slice(1);
      setTasks((prevState) => ([...prevState,{ id: index, name: taskName }]));
        });
})
   }

   const interval = setInterval(() => {
          fetchData();
         }, 5000)
   return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, []);
```

please do not forget two things:

1. This approach is only good when you have 5 to 10 simultaneous clients  connected since it is not performance effective on the backend, I would recommend instead an alternative based on realtime communication (with the listening for new events.
2. please do not forget to specify the {method, headers, body) in the fetch function